# How to get the dimensions/placement of HTML element(s) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, overlay

I'm trying to get the height, width, and placement of a section of HTML code, so that I can create a `<div>` with `position: absolute` to overlay the HTML in question. Sometimes this HTML is a single element, other times it's a bunch of elements.

I've tried to wrap the HTML code in question in a `<span>` and then use `$('#spanToMeasure').height()` and `.width()` and `.offset()`, but I'm getting inconsistent results. Sometimes the height and/or width returns as 0, when it really isn't, and sometimes the placement is off.

I've also tried using `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`, but the results appear the same.

Is my method not working due to CSS that's changing the dimensions/placement? Or is something else going on? Any help is appreciated!

Here's my full code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Create a container to hold all of the overlays.
    var $overlayContainer = $('<div id="easy_edit_overlays">').appendTo('body');

    // Find all of the sections of code to create overlays for.
    $('span.easy_edit').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.removeClass('easy_edit');

      var height = $this.height();
      var width = $this.width();

      var offset = $this.offset();

      // Create overlay.
      var $editOverlay = $('<div>').addClass('easy_edit_overlay')
                                   .height(height)
                                   .width(width)
                                   .css('background-color', 'red')
                                   .css('opacity', '0.5')
                                   .css('top', offset.top)
                                   .css('left', offset.left)
                                   .css('position', 'absolute');

      // Create link to include within overlay.
      var $editLink = $('<a>').attr('href', $this.attr('class'))
                              .attr('target', '_blank')
                              .css('display', 'block')
                              .css('height', height)
                              .css('color', 'red')
                              .text('Edit');

      $editLink.appendTo($editOverlay);

      $editOverlay.appendTo($overlayContainer);

      // Remove the <span> tag and replace with its children.
      $this.replaceWith($this.html());
    });
  });
```

Comment: You'll get "unexpected" `.height()` and `.width()` of `0` when the element has `display: none;`. Are your elements hidden when you're trying to measure them?

Comment: No, they're all visible. The wrapping `<span>` doesn't seem to be computing the correct size of the elements within.

Comment: Can you post the html you're working with, too? I'd be interested in running this myself, to see if I can work see why things aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is most likely due to the fact that a `<span>` is an inline element, which means its dimensions may not be correctly computed.  See this article for a description on the way a few attributes apply differently between block and inline elements: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

As to the positioning, you may want to review the difference between `.offset()` and `.position()`.  I've linked the documentation for both below:

- [.position() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/position/)
- [.offset() Documenation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

EDIT:

This doesn't really address the specific problem you're having, but I do have a suggestion to make your life easier.  There already exists a plug-in called [ternElapse](http://www.ternstyle.us/products/plugins/jquery/jquery-ternelapse) that does exactly what you want to do.  Maybe you could use that, instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Hopefully they have already addressed the problem you're tackling and found the solution :)

Comment: Wrapping the code in a `<div>` gives the correct offset now, but I'm still getting heights of 0 in some instances.

Comment: Are by chance all of the elements floated? That will cause the height to be zero.

Comment: Yes, in fact, it looks like the problematic elements are floated. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I've added a suggestion for a plug-in to my answer.  Hopefully it is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easily accomplished:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#elementID').click(
            function(){
                var position = $('#elementID').offset(),
                xPos = position.left,
                yPos = position.top,
                width = $('#elementID').width(); // or $('#element').outerWidth(),
                height = $('#elementID').height();
                $('#x').text('xPos: ' + xPos);
                $('#y').text('yPos: ' + yPos);
                $('#h').text('Height: ' + height);
                $('#w').text('Width: ' + width);
            });
    }
);
```

[Demo at: JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ANQW/)

For the inconsistent results, it's worth checking the following:

1. Whether you're positioning the `position: absolute` element against the correct container (its parent needs to have a specified `position` attribute, otherwise it just bubbles up to be positioned against the first ancestor with a specified `position`).
2. Whether the elements you're finding the height of exist in the DOM at the time the function is run.
3. Whether the elements have `display: visible`.
4. That the values you're working with in your functions aren't being manipulated by another source elsewhere in your script.

Comment: Did you actually read the question? Or look at his code?  He's already using everything you've mentioned here.

Comment: @Ender, yes; I did. Hence the edits. I was proving to myself that his code *should* work before I tried to find what the problem(s) might be. Saying it was *pretty easy* does come across as a little crass, though...

Comment: Sorry, I was being a little overly hostile there.  Thanks for adding more to your answer :)

Comment: @Ender, no worries; I've reacted in much the same way myself sometimes; and, to be fair, I should've posted some suggestions in the original posting of my answer (rather than posted working code and *then* tried to rationalise the problems and editing-in...) =)

Answer (score 0):

A `span` element is an inline element, so it doesn't always cover a square area that can be covered with a `div` element. It can for example contain two words, and one word is at the end of a line, and the other word is at the beginning of the next line. That would make the `span` consist of two rectangular areas.

If you want an element that you can always get the size and position of, you should use a block element.